# Server with 2 NICs

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter

The server has a motherboard with built-in NIC that has 2 Ethernet ports. 1st labeled Management, 2nd isn't labeled anything. 2nd NIC is a PCI card plugged into the motherboard, which has 1 Ethernet port.

What is the difference between Ethernet port labelled Management and the rest? When should I use more than one NICs with many Ethernet ports?

I want to use this server for random stuff like a web server and a small game server running in ESXi.

Comment: The management port is probably connected to some on-board "Lights Out Management" system and likely not directly visible to any OS you install on it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many server and workstation class boards come with remote management options. Depending on the board (and sometimes on a license) you can use these to remote control the server.

Example:
a Dell server with a regular DRAC (Dell Remote Access) has a mini computer build into it which can communicate with a dedicated management Ethernet port. That mini computer can simulate mouse and keyboard events and it can capture the screen output. In other words: you can connect to the management card and do all mostly the same things as if you were physically behind the computer. E.g. power it up and down (without needing an OS, or in case of a crashed OS). You can use the local keyboard and local mouse as if they were connected to the server. You can see what is on the screen... Very handy for remote management.

Similar abilities are available in other brands, often marked ilo (integrated lights out)

Such a device needs to communicate and for that it usually uses an ethernet port. Either a dedicated one (which will be marked 'management' and which will not be useable for the normal OS or it shares one with the normal OS. The latter is more fragile.

Comment: Does that mean I should have both Management and one normal Ethernet port connected to the network if I want to remote into the server? Can't I just use a normal Ethernet port and then use vSphere/Windows RDP? Granted I won't be able to use BIOS/Boot settings.

Comment: You can use the normal Ethernet port and RDP in. No problem there. But the management port might allow you do do much more. E.g. enter the BIOS, partition disks from the RAID cards setup, select a remove iso on your computer to act as a virtual CDROM so that you can (re)install and OS. Access the PC after the OS has crashed/purple-screened.  It simply is much more capable. But you can use both.